# Why does After Effects cut some last seconds of video in Timeline?

Tags: after-effects

I have a video asset that is 1:57 long. When I import it to AE, in Project window it suddenly shows that video is only 1:49;15f long! Why does it happen and how can I get my extra 8 seconds back?

Those 8 hidden seconds contain sound that I need to work with.

UPD: here's all the data about this video asset (taken with MediaInfo software):

```
General
Complete name                            : D:\work\nuzhnapomosh\SPEC\Cage\thecage_elements_animated\Klekta trailer New Text v02.mov
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : QuickTime
Codec ID                                 : qt   2005.03 (qt  )
File size                                : 263 MiB
Duration                                 : 1 min
Overall bit rate                         : 18.8 Mb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-08-28 07:18:49
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-08-28 07:19:04
Writing library                          : Apple QuickTime

Video
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L4
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 2 frames
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=50
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1 min
Bit rate                                 : 18.6 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.359
Stream size                              : 244 MiB (92%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-08-28 07:18:49
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-08-28 07:19:04
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings, Endianness              : Big
Format settings, Sign                    : Signed
Codec ID                                 : twos
Duration                                 : 1 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 411.2 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 19.7 MiB (8%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-08-28 07:18:49
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-08-28 07:19:04

Other
ID                                       : 4
Type                                     : Time code
Format                                   : QuickTime TC
Duration                                 : 1 min
Time code of first frame                 : 00:06:15:21
Time code, striped                       : Yes
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-08-28 07:18:49
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-08-28 07:19:04
```

Comment: Is it variable frame rate?

Comment: @Mulvya I don't know how to check it, could you please tell me? It seems that my video asset did not just changed its frame rate, but it lacks some seconds which were not empty

Comment: Check using [mediainfo](http://mediaarea.net). Use View -> Text mode.

Comment: Nice soft, thanks! It tells me that the frame rate is "Constant" and equals 25fps

Comment: What duration does it show for audio and video?

Comment: It shows all Durations as only "1 min". Very strange rounding

Comment: Can you paste the output into the Q?

Comment: You mean "into the question"?

Comment: Yes, as code-formatted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44689/discussion-between-aksana-zinchanka-and-mulvya).

Comment: What settings are you using in the **interpret footage** dialog in AE?

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the video to Quicktime ProRes format, or another format that doesn't have intra-frame compression before you import it into After Effects.

Comment: *that doesn't have intra-frame compression* --> does**n't** ?